# "correlation" between two subspaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

It is frequently important to determine the coherence of a matrix by finding the maximum pairwise correlation between all its column vectors. Similarly, when working with a union of subspaces of a Hilbert space it would be convenient to have a measure of similarity between two different subspaces. Does such a measure exist? And how is it computed? Assume I have an orthonormal basis for each subspace, but the subspaces are not necessarily the same dimension.

Importantly, I do not want this to be a supremum measure; i.e., if two subspaces share a single basis vector, they should not necessarily have a correlation of 1.

Comment: How about $\| P_V - P_W \|$ where $P_V$ is the projection onto $V$? This is more of a distance and less of a similarity, but at least it's a reasonably canonical choice.

Comment: I'm a little confused about that statement. Is $P_V$ a projection matrix? Is it an operator? How do you compute $P_V - P_W$?

Comment: Also, what norm are you using?

Comment: $P_V$ is a projection operator (you're working in a Hilbert space, right?) and the norm is the operator norm.